# React Native Animations singleValue.stopTracking is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I try to implement a sliding bar and bond the sliding animation to a `TouchableOpacity`.
I initialized the parameter as `sliderPosition: new Animated.Value(0)`
the onPress function is :

```
  onPress: function(event){
    Animated.timing(this.state.sliderPosition, {
      toValue: 202.5, 
      duration: 100,
      easing: Easing.linear, 
    }).start();
  },
```

I kept getting this error

`[tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: singleValue.stopTracking is not a function. (In 'singleValue.stopTracking()', 'singleValue.stopTracking' is undefined)`

layout for the slider is:

```
    <View style = {styles.sliderContainer}>
      <Animated.View style = {[styles.slider, {marginLeft:this.state.sliderPosition}]}>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
```

styles:

```
sliderContainer: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 138,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  height: 5,
  backgroundColor: '#E15668',
  shadowRadius: 1,
  shadowOpacity: 0.5,
  shadowColor: 'gray',
  shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
  opacity: 0.9
},
slider: {
  marginTop: 0,
  backgroundColor: '#FCC31B',
  width: 120,
  height: 5,
},
```

did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `sliderPosition` property on your state remains an instance of Animated.Value? That error you're getting speaks to that being the issue. Here is a complete example using your code snippets that works as you'd expect. Try this out and if the snippet doesn't help solve your issue, please post more of your surrounding code to lend more context:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  AppRegistry,
  Easing,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      sliderPosition: new Animated.Value(0)
    }
  }

  onPress(event){
    Animated.timing(this.state.sliderPosition, {
      toValue: 202.5, 
      duration: 100,
      easing: Easing.linear, 
    }).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
          <Text>Animate It</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style = {styles.sliderContainer}>
          <Animated.View style = {[styles.slider, {marginLeft:this.state.sliderPosition}]}>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  sliderContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 138,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#E15668',
    shadowRadius: 1,
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowColor: 'gray',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
    opacity: 0.9
  },

  slider: {
    marginTop: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#FCC31B',
    width: 120,
    height: 5,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply. I'm pretty much sure the sliderPosition is an instance of Animated.Value. I've put mu code here https://rnplay.org/apps/86JeRA and it works fine